# RelativeLayout: can't use layout_below with link to a LinearLayout child?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have a RelativeLayout which has a LinearLayout as a child containing TextViews.

I would like to place ImageViews at the right side of the TextViews with layout_alignRight="@id/userdetail_tv_special" but somehow this is not working.

Can't I "link" a child of a RelativeLayout to a child of a LinearLayout? Any ideas how i could achieve this without creating another RelativeLayout for each Button?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/userdetail_lin_btncontainer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/userdetail_lin_divider" 
        android:padding="6dp" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/userdetail_tv_special"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Special"
            android:background="#cccccc" />
        <!-- here are more TextViews like this one -->
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/userdetail_tv_special"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_detail_special" />
        <!-- much more views and stuff -->
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would seem logical to me that you cannot point to a "layour" deeper: you can layout the children of a RelativeLayout against each-other, but you LinearLayout is a complete view that you can use as a reference.

If you want to be able to position views relative to the textview, place them as direct children of the relativelayout. I do not see why you would need a LinearLayout here by the way.

Comment: The LinearLayout has 5 TextViews with layout_width=fill_parent and layout_weigth=1 to strech them to fill out the whole width of the screen ... is there another possibility to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imgview"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_detail_special" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/userdetail_lin_btncontainer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/userdetail_lin_divider" 
   android:layout_alignLeft="@id/imgview"
    android:padding="6dp" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userdetail_tv_special"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Special"
        android:background="#cccccc" />
    <!-- here are more TextViews like this one -->
</LinearLayout>

      <!-- much more views and stuff -->
```